# how to instantiate the imported class in angular

Tags: angular, api

i am working on a angualr weather app. 
for which i have created weather class

```
 export class Weather{
          city: string;
          condition: string;
          icon: string;
          temp: number;
        }
```

and i make a http api request for weather details.

i have imported this `Weather` class and want to assign the fields as per the json object from the api call.

like this.

```
weather:Weather;
getWeather():void{
               this.weatherserv.getWeather().subscribe(data=>{
                   this.weather.city=data.location.name;
                  this.weather.condition=data.condition.text;
                   this.weather.condition=data.condition.icon;
                   this.weather.temp=data.current.temp_c;
               })
             }
```

Error i am getting is:

```
Error: Cannot set property 'city' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
weather: Weather =  new Weather();
getWeather():void{
           this.weatherserv.getWeather().subscribe(data=>{
               this.weather.city=data.location.name;
              this.weather.condition=data.condition.text;
               this.weather.condition=data.condition.icon;
               this.weather.temp=data.current.temp_c;
           })
         }
```

Answer (score 3):

you should try:

```
weather= new Weather();
```

or in your case, it's better to use interfaces:

```
 export interface Weather{
          city?: string;
          condition?: string;
          icon?: string;
          temp?: number;
        }
weather:Weather = {};
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51453368/8990367) i explained why it's better to use interfaces in your case.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. +1 for using interface instead of class

Comment: yes i it's better to use interfaces here not class, i think it should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Test follow code:

```
weather: Weather = new Weather;
```

Here: [the stackblitz for it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nk7h9h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

you should create a new object from your class and then set values for that .